# Optimal framework to distribute a Python program across n cores

Tags: python, apache-spark, distributed-computing

I'm new to distributed systems and have been tasked with the objective of distributing a piece of existing Python code. The goal is to treat the code as a binary or a library and author two different kinds of wrappers:

- **Wrapper 1:** Receives large datastreams from the environment, *invokes the Python code* to perform some computation on it and then breaks it up and sends the chunks of data (and some other things) to the worker nodes. Runs in the master node.
- **Wrapper 2:** Receives those chunks of data, *invokes the Python code* to do some computation on them and when a particular condition is met, sends data back to the master node.

The process is repeated until no further data comes to the master node. It can be exemplified by the following figure:[image: A high-level view of the desired distributed architecture.]

So there exists both

(1) The need for communication between the workers and the master node as well as

(2) The need for invocation of existing Python code.

It is also important that the entire framework views the notion of "node" agnostically, since it needs to be run on either a personal computer where nodes equate cores (physical or virtual) or on a cluster, where nodes can be entire computers with a number of cores each. I'm therefore looking for a technology that can help me achieve this plethora of goals. I'm already studying up on Apache Spark, yet I'm not entirely sure whether Spark will allow me to execute Python code in a streamlined fashion, and was looking for ideas.

Comment: So what's your question and why did you give it the spark tag?

Comment: My question is whether the community believes that Spark would be a suitable platform for developing this application. As pre-mentioned, I'm completely new to distributed applications, and am looking to perform an informed search on the space of possible technologies. I would not want to decide upon Pyspark, only to realize down the road that it can't view nodes in an abstract form or that it won't allow me to import basic Python libraries required by the code to be distributed.

If it is hypothesized that the "apache-spark" tag is superfluous, it can be removed.

Comment: apache-spark dedicated for large scale data processing. So you should ask you self how large your data processing actually is?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`celery`](http://www.celeryproject.org/) as an easy option:

> **Celery: Distributed Task Queue**
>
> Celery is an asynchronous task
>   queue/job queue based on distributed message passing. It is focused on
>   real-time operation, but supports scheduling as well. The execution
>   units, called tasks, are executed concurrently on a single or more
>   worker servers using multiprocessing, Eventlet,   or gevent. Tasks can
>   execute asynchronously (in the background) or synchronously (wait
>   until ready).
>
> Celery is used in production systems to process millions
>   of tasks a day.